# Resharper update namespace on all files in project

Tags: c#

I know i can update my current files namespace to match the directory structure.  Can i do this all at once for all files in a project.

Comment: Solution is available now in ReShaper see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179653/1938982)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this OOB.

But, you can update them fairly quickly through the Class View window. Open class view window, click on the namespace you want to rename, hit CTRL + R + R and then rename.

[This blog post outlines it very well](http://rickardnilsson.net/post/2008/08/26/ReSharper-User-tip-2-Refactor-rename-namespace.aspx)