# Fastest way to update namespaces with ReSharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have been doing some refactoring and reorganization and I have moved a bunch of files around.

I want to update each file so it has the "correct" namespace according to its new location. With ReSharper, I can go into each file and it shows me that the namespaces is incorrect but that way I have to do it each file at a time.

Is there anyway to update namespaces across every file in a folder or a project?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

**UPDATE: Anyone reading this question with R#5.0 and above should note that [this is now a feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html):**

ReSharper -> Refactor -> Adjust Namespaces...

Comment: +1 - select the files and right click -> refactor ->adjust namespaces, the option is greyed out if you are inside a file in the editor

Comment: This feature alone is why ReSharper is worth its money. Total time saver when you are restructuring your solutions.

Comment: Probably also worth pointing out that you can scope a namespace refactor to a solution or project level simply by highlighting the appropriate container in Solution Explorer.

Comment: To expand even more on Chris Pickford's comment: as of ReSharper 9, you can also refactor namespaces at the folder or file levels.  Select the appropriate container in Solution Explorer, right-click and select "Refactor > Adjust Namespaces".

Answer (score 7):

This isn't quite what you want to do ... but hopefully it's helpful.

Go to the class view, and rename the namespace using Ctrl+R,R. It will update that namespace in all the files/folders that it's used in. As long as your namespaces are consistant, it should acheive the same result as changing all the namespaces in a folder.

If your namespaces aren't consistant, and you're just tidying up then I'm afraid you've got a lot of clicking in front of you (or behind you as you've probably already done this).

Answer (score 1):

I think that R# doesn't have this function.
You can use CTRL-SHIFT-H to find&replace the string.

Comment: can you do find /replace just in a folder?

Comment: yes, you can do find/replace in a folder: in the Find In Files dialog, click the button with an ellipse next to the 'Look In' field, then specify your target folder(s)