# ReSharper: Rename namespace not available?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, resharper

I'm trying to rename a namespace. For some reason, ReSharper isn't giving me the option to do so. I right click on it and choose **Refactor**, but everything except "Convert" is greyed out. I try the key combination CTRL R + R, and it says the command is unavailable. What am I doing wrong?

Here is documentation suggesting that what I am trying to do should work:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/renaming.html#renameNamespace

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with R# 4.5

Comment: Is the cursor at the namespace identifier?

Comment: I have the same problem. Maybe because I am offline with regard to TFS? However, all other refactorings seem to work ...

Comment: could you comment on my answer?

Answer (score 3):

I have come across this before and the answer is very subtle. Do not select (eg by double clicking) the entire method name(or namespace if renaming a namespace). Instead, ensure the method name is deselected and place the caret over the method name.
eg

[image]

**NOT** this

[image]

When you select the Convert menu the items should now be available for methods, and 'Rename' will become available if you had the caret over a namespace.
In my mind this should be changed, it is not obvious.

Comment: Does not help me, also when I press Ctrl + R, Ctrl + R it selects the entire property name, which is exactly what you said I should not do...

Comment: its `Ctrl+R, R` by the way. I'm using R# 8.0 and it now works if selected or not. what resharper version ru using?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the way to do this now is via `ReSharper => Refactor => Adjust Namespaces` menu or open the Class View, right click on the namespace you wanted to rename and again select `Refactor => Adjust Namespaces`.

See also: [Fastest way to update namespaces with ReSharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791253/fastest-way-to-update-namespaces-resharper)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I just had this problem. Closing Visual Studio and re-opening it fixed the problem for me. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue but I just had this and perhaps know a workaround.
Since someone has commented just yesterday timing could not be more perfect.
Anyways,
I had the same issue and was finally able to do a rename refactoring on my namespace.

- I chose one of the classes in my project and did the move to another namespace refactor.
- Then I was able to go to another class and do the rename namespace refactor.

Perhaps a bug in Resharper that if the namespace is consistent throughout the class then it's disabled?  Unlikely since this was reported as far back as 4.5...